# Difference between amazon,parse,pushwoosh & default GCM push notification for android?

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, pushwoosh

which push notification is best and what is the difference between amazon,parse,pushwoosh and default GCM?

i want to integrate push notification for my android app
when i google i got the above options
im confuse which one is effective and best push notification. please help me out clarify the confusion between all of them.

Comment: And you missed Urban Airship! I don't have experience with Amazon or Pushwoosh, but for the others: Both Urban Airship and Parse have their own web interfaces for sending pushes and SDKs for receiving pushes. I find both to be equally easy to use: Once you know what goes where you can easily set up a new app and include Parse/Urban Airship in a two hours. To use GCM directly I think you have a lot more you need to do yourself: Implement your own server app to store the devices IDs for example...

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is Parse is free push notification service, while amazon and pushwoosh are paid services. Pushwoosh has excellent UI to send notification with customised options like sending notification to specific devices, common interface for android ios blacberry i.e. multi platform support.

Amazon and parse dont have such kind of UI for sending notification.

Comment: I don't know about Amazon but I find's Parse's web interface for sending pushes to be both existent and nice.

Comment: parse.com is free for few hits , then you have to pay for this

Comment: Parse is shutting down on January 28, 2017 - http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/